# Input to reshape is a tensor with 40960 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 524288

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, lstm, tensorflow2.0

On implementing this - https://github.com/Jatin-7/aiFinal
We are getting the following error

PS D:\AIPROJECTISL> python train.py
2022-04-19 19:15:55.972422: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-04-19 19:15:55.973523: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-04-19 19:16:05.871919: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2022-04-19 19:16:05.872585: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:269] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2022-04-19 19:16:05.881848: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: DESKTOP-RA828CK
2022-04-19 19:16:05.882300: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: DESKTOP-RA828CK
2022-04-19 19:16:05.883017: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Found 1608 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 1608 images belonging to 5 classes.
Epoch 1/5
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\AIPROJECTISL\train.py", line 97, in 
classifier.fit(
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sequential/time_distributed/Reshape_1' defined at (most recent call last):
File "D:\AIPROJECTISL\train.py", line 97, in 
classifier.fit(
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1384, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1021, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1010, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1000, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 859, in train_step
y_pred = self(x, training=True)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1096, in **call**
outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 374, in call
return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 451, in call
return self._run_internal_graph(
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1096, in **call**
outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py", line 275, in call
y = tf.**internal**.nest.map_structure_up_to(y, tf.reshape, y, output_shape)
Node: 'sequential/time_distributed/Reshape_1'
Input to reshape is a tensor with 40960 values, but the requested shape requires a multiple of 524288
[[{{node sequential/time_distributed/Reshape_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7769]
2022-04-19 19:16:20.860571: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
[[{{node PyFunc}}]]

Comment: Welcome to SO, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.